# How do you display previous answers of a DIFFERENT survey participant in qualtrics survey?

Tags: qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics to elicit responses of a group of 12 subjects. To be specific, let me label each subject with an ID =(1,2,...,12).

I would like to create 6 pairs. Towards the end of the survey, I would like to show ID 2 the response of ID 1 to an earlier question. I would like to show ID 4 the response of ID 3, etc.

I know how to use piped text to display show ID 2 his previous answers. But I'd like to show the previous answers of ID 1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pipe across different responses. I think the only way to do this would be to to write a web service script that uses the Qualtrics REST API to get response data for a different respondent. You would only be able to access response data for other respondents who had already completed the survey.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a webservice to push to(and pull from) a personal database. Then you could do it real time as they are both in the survey.